# Finding values by each specialty

Tags: r

I have a dataset column with different medical specialties but the specialties repeat and for each row there is a count. I want to sum the values for each specialty and also ignore the rows with less than 10. How do I do this in R?

For Ex:

```
        Col1   Col2 
Internal Med     11
Internal Med     12
   Neurology      5
   Neurology     13
Internal Med      9
```

I should get `Internal Med- 12 + 11` (9 is ignored)
             `Neurology- 13` (5 is ignored)

Answer (score 1):

```
# method 1:
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[Col2 > 10, sum(Col2),by = .(Col1)]

# OR
# method 2
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Col1) %>% 
       filter(Col2 > 10) %>% 
       summarise(sum(Col2))

#           Col1 `sum(Col2)`
# 1 Internal_Med          23
# 2    Neurology          13
```

Comment: What is %>%? I am confused, should I Use the first method or the second method or both?

Comment: @RikinMathur its a operator... anyone of the methods

Comment: Thanks but it says Error: could not find function "%>%"

Comment: `%>%` is part of the `magrittr` package, which the `dplyr` package loads automatically. It has the same function as the pipe `|` in linux/unix if that helps. There are a number of related questions on SO that describe it.

Comment: ok it worked but now i am getting an error that group_by can't group by that column. Do i need to provide each specialty name?

Comment: @RikinMathur here `df` refers to the name of your dataframe. crosscheck the column names

Comment: @RikinMathur also i hope the explanation if done by code itself... do you have any questions on what it's doing?

Comment: @joel.wilson probably we need to do the `filter` first and then do `group_by` with `dplyr`.

Comment: @SandipanDey seems yeah that can benefit a little

Answer (score 0):

purly `base` based solution :

```
data <- data.frame(
Col1=c("IM", "IM", "N", "N", "IM"),
Col2=c(11, 12, 5, 13, 9)
)

# sums in groups
aggregate(data$Col2, by=list(data$Col1), FUN=sum)

# sums in groups for obs with Col2 >=10
aggregate(data$Col2[data$Col2>=10], by=list(data$Col1[data$Col2>=10]), FUN=sum)
```

(but I prefer `dplyr`)

Answer (score 0):

With `base R`:

```
aggregate(Col2~Col1, subset(df, Col2 >= 10), sum)
#            Col1 Col2
#1   Internal Med   23
#2      Neurology   13
```

or

```
subdf <- subset(df, Col2 >= 10)
as.data.frame(Col2=tapply(subdf$Col2, subdf$Col1, sum))
#               Col2
# Internal Med   23
# Neurology      13
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be using [xtabs](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/xtabs.html):

```
xtabs( Col2 ~ Col1, df, subset = Col2>10 )
```